# Elasticsearch: How to query for number of connections?

Tags: curl, networking, elasticsearch, get, connection

How do I ask my Elasticsearch server how many connections are open to it right now?

Is this the same as the number of sockets?  (I don't know how to get these numbers, either)

And this is different from the number of clients, right, since each client may open multiple connections?

Could not find any info on this, though I did find that you could specify a maxSockets per client on the Elasticsearch client side: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/configuration.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The request layer uses a RESTful API, so connections don't stay open after any request has been served.

So if you're trying to gauge how many concurrent requests Elasticsearch is serving (whether it's query, index or bulk), you probably want to monitor the thread_pool on each node:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-stats.html

Or are you looking for more info into the discovery layer?

Comment: Ah.  Thanks.  I didn't realize that ES doesn't offer persistent connections between the client and the nodes.  So I take it that clients always make a new connection to an ES node for each operation?

Comment: And nope, you were right- I'm looking into client-server connections, not the discovery layer (which looks like it's node-node)

Comment: "The request layer uses a RESTful API, so connections don't stay open after any request has been served." HTTP TCP/IP connections can remain open after the completion of an HTTP request+response.

Comment: The assumption that connections don't stay open "because restful api" is incorrect. Any well behaved Elasticsearch client will use HTTP keepalive to avoid re-connecting for every request.

Answer (score 6):

ES don't have number of connections.

But you can get some information about ES health, more info [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-health.html):

```
curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/health?v'
```

And you can obtain extended statistics about shards, segments, indexes, searches counts and so on... more info [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html) :

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_stats'
```